# Reinject dependencies of a freshly deserialized object

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ioc-container, autofac

If a program has literally just deserialized an object (doesn't really matter how, but just say BinaryFormatter was used).

What is a good design to use for re-injecting the dependencies of this object?

Is there a common pattern for this?

I suppose I would need to wrap the Deserialize() method up to act as a factory inside the container.

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You shouldn't serialize objects with dependencies that can't themselves be serialized.

Instead, split it into two classes: **extract the serializable parts into a separate class**.

After deserializing, you can associate the resulting object with an instance of the original class (the one with dependencies).

Comment: "All problems in computer science can be solved by another level of indirection, except for the problem of too many layers of indirection."

Comment: I think of my suggestion as *removing* a layer of indirection. (Or at least removing the need for an additional one!) ;)

Comment: Have to admit Jeff, this was a possible solution that crossed the back of my mind. I have implemented it now and the codebase is better for it :)

Comment: But what if I have XP and Level properties in my Character entity and the level is calculated from XP with my Formulas class instance which is not serialized? I don't want to have these Level and XP properties on seperate objects!

Answer (score 1):

I would use the [OnDeserialized](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ondeserializedattribute(v=VS.100).aspx) attribute to point at a method that would do the re-injection.

Comment: But that would surely require a dependency upon the container itself i.e. breaking the golden IoC rule?

Comment: Not true if you are using something like Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation you are container-neutral.

Comment: Container-neutral, but still dependent on the container.

Comment: You could use a static class and send the object there, the method on that class would take of the injection then.

Answer (score 0):

Unity has a concept of "[BuildUp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc440949.aspx)" where you can ask it to fulfil the dependencies of an existing object. I don't know if autofac (which I presume you are using from the tags) has an equivalent.

Comment: Property injection is the Autofac equvivalent